# Salesforce id fields vs 3rd party text field

Tags: custom-field, data-loader

For a custom object , we have a lookup field Account which will be holding the id of the Account which the user will be selecting .

We need to import data from a 3rd party where the Account field is text .

How to insert such data?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'the Account field is text'? Can you provide a small sample of the data to be imported?

Comment: you have account name in that text field or account id?

Comment: e.g In Salesforce , the Account field is a Lookup one . But in the data , Account field is text . Like ABCD

Comment: Should I get the Account ids first , put it in this sheet and then insert?

Comment: you can try the [Dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io). In this tool they provide option to match parent using any parent object field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data Loader Option**

1. Create a report in Salesforce of the Account Names (or whichever field you are going to match on) and Id then export to Excel.
2. Import this into excel as one sheet in the workbook, sort these by the acccount name or other field you will be using for matching.
3. Create a separate sheet with the external data and then create a Vlookupfield to the sheet containing the Salesforce data and id, returning the column value for the id.
4. Export this sheet with the external data to a .csv file and load to Salesforce using Data Loader.

[Data Loader Documentation](http://eu11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_loader.htm)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Option use Import Wizard**

The Data Import Wizard will allow you to match Salesforce fields using text values, e.g. account name, rather than the Id. See the image below though there I am matching user rather than account name the principle is the same.

[image: Data Import Wizard]

Setup>Administration>Data Management>Data Import Wizard

This will work better if you have less than 50,000 records to import or can batch them up.

[Data Import Wizard help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_import_wizard.htm&language=en)

Comment: It would be better if you merge both answer in one.

Comment: I was looking at this meta thread http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/one-answer-with-multiple-solutions-or-mutliple-answers-with-one-solution-each - so unsure whether to have 1 or 2 answers.

Comment: I'm with Dave here on the two answers for the reasons given in meta